# Laravel cache DB raw query

Tags: caching, laravel

I have this query in Laravel, how can I cache it for like 10 minutes?

```
$sorted_taxonomy_record = DB::select(
    DB::raw(
        'select level1.id as level1, level2.id as level2 from taxonomies as level1 
        left outer join taxonomies as level2 on level2.parent_id = level1.id 
        where level1.parent_id = ' . $taxonomy->id . ' order by level1, level2'
    )
);
```

adding ->remember(10) at the end of it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Cache::remember` method:

```php
$sorted_taxonomy_record = Cache::remember('sorted_taxonomy_record', 10 , function()
{
    return DB::select(
            DB::raw(
                'select level1.id as level1, level2.id as level2 from taxonomies as level1 
                left outer join taxonomies as level2 on level2.parent_id = level1.id 
                where level1.parent_id = ' . $taxonomy->id . ' order by level1, level2'
            )
    );
});
```

**But** it is recommended to use [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries):

```php
$sorted_taxonomy_record = DB::table('taxonomies as level1')
    ->select('level1.id as level1','level2.id as level2')
    ->join('taxonomies as level2', 'level2.parent_id', '=', 'level1.id', 'left outer')
    ->where('level1.parent_id','=',$taxonomy->id)
    ->orderBy('level1')
    ->orderBy('level2')
    ->remember(10,'sorted_taxonomy_record')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works, except that I need to make a little twick:
  $sorted_taxonomy_record = DB::table('taxonomies as level1')
         ->select(DB::raw('level1.id as level1, level2.id as level2'))
         ->join('taxonomies as level2', 'level2.parent_id', '=', 'level1.id', 'left outer')
         ->where('level1.parent_id', $taxonomy->id)
         ->orderBy('level1')
         ->orderBy('level2')
         ->remember(10)
         ->get();

Comment: It works without using `select(DB::raw('...'))` (Laravel 4.2.1), you got an error message or what ? For information, the second argument in `remember` method is the `key`, so maybe if you want to clear that cache, you can do `Cache::forget('sorted_taxonomy_record');` (e.g., when updating `taxonomies` table)

Comment: By removing the DB::raw('...'), I got the following error message:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'level1' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `level1`.`id` as `level1,` from `taxonomies` as `level1` left outer join `taxonomies` as `level2` on `level2`.`parent_id` = `level1`.`id` where `level1`.`parent_id` = 1 order by `level1` asc, `level2` asc)

Comment: By the way, this query is used in a loop. The loop loops through all the  root taxonomies that has no parent, so I wonder if Laravel remembers/caches each of the query automatically?

Comment: I think yes but **if** you don't specify the second parameter in `remember` method, to check it by your self add this code in "routes.php" file `Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql){var_dump($sql);});` so you can see all generated queries

Comment: Thanks for the tip of showing queries for current route, learned something new, however the query doesn't cache, while iterating each root taxonomy and trying to fetch all of its offsprings, the query runs everytime, i.e. NOT CACHED... any ideas?

Comment: I think at least one query will be cached, anyway add `remember(10,'sorted_taxonomy_record'.$key)` method inside `foreach ($taxonomies as $key => $taxonomy)`. If it's not working, please ask a new question or edit this one.